# filtering in a table by ignoring the records those are unnecessary anymore

Tags: oracle

I have a table including CONTRACT_ID, ADDENDUM_ID and PAYMENT_MONTH (payment dates of a yearly contract).
Everytime an update occurs for any reason in the system:

1. ADDENDUM_ID udates as +1
2. PAYMENT_MONTH records are duplicated for the remaining months

In attached picture I tried to explain in detail using an example (a contract with 3 updates).
The question is how to write a query to get a summary table ignoring the duplicated but unnecessary records (grey filled ones) because of a new update on addendum column.
Please note that there are hundreds of contracts in the original table, while the example contains only one.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What software did you use to create that diagram?

Comment: Have you tried "select contact_id, payment_month, max(addendum_id) from original_table group by contact_id, payment_month"?

Comment: @TenG, it is excel.     I think the code you have suggested only gives the records with maximum addendum_id, in this case last three records..

Comment: The first 12 line belongs to addendum_id 1, these records created at the beginning of the contract and this is the first update.
Then on 5th month there was 2nd update and the remaining months' records (5 to 12) were duplicated in the table. 
Then on 10th month there was 3rd update and the remaining months' records (10 to 12) were duplicated again.

What I want is to get the months 1 to 4 from addendum_id 1 , months 5-9 from addendum_id 2  and finally months 10 to 12 from addendum_id 3. I want to do it dynamically because there may be addendum_id's more than 3 in the original table.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your desired output, maybe this can help:

```
with test(contract_id, addendum_id, payment_month) as
(
    select 155, 1, 1 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 3 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 4 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 5 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 6 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 7 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 8 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 9 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 11 from dual union all
    select 155, 1, 12 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 5 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 6 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 7 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 8 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 9 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 10 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 11 from dual union all
    select 155, 2, 12 from dual union all
    select 155, 3, 10 from dual union all
    select 155, 3, 11 from dual union all
    select 155, 3, 12 from dual       
)
select contract_id, addendum_id, payment_month from (
    select      
           max(addendum_id)  over ( partition by payment_month) as max_addendum_id,
           contract_id, payment_month, addendum_id
    from test
)
where max_addendum_id = addendum_id
order by 1, 2, 3
```